# Async Controller Actions in F#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, f#

Using C# - ASP.NET MVC 4, I can define an async controller action like:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> IndexWorks()
{
    var data = await DownloadAsync("http://stackoverflow.com");
    return Content(data);
}
```

Is there a way to do something similar, using F#?

I'm aware of that I could use the [`AsyncManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#converting_synchronous_action_methods_to_asynchronous_action_methods) approach. I'm also aware of that @Tomas Petricek have made a quite neat [`AsyncActionBuilder`](http://fssnip.net/4z), but it just feels like a lot of boilerplate, compared to the C# approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually seems like a fellow programmer, Dmitry Morozov have made such thing possible. He have made a custom `AsyncWorkflowController` that makes it possible to return `Async<ActionResult>` from an `ActionResult`. The code for the `AsyncWorkFlowController` can be found at http://fssnip.net/5q.

However, his implementation makes it very difficult to debug, due to the fact that the stack trace wont be preserved when rethrowen in the custom controller. Therefore I've made a little change to make this possible:

```
 member actionDesc.EndExecute(asyncResult) =
    match endAsync'.Value(asyncResult) with
        | Choice1Of2 value -> box value
        | Choice2Of2 why -> 
            // Preserve the stack trace, when rethrow 
            ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(why).Throw() 
            obj() (* Satisfy return value *) } } }
```

Also I've changed the following line: `new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(controllerType)`,

to `new ReflectedAsyncControllerDescriptor(controllerType)` - However this change is purely optional, as it wont make any difference. I just found it more logical to use the `Async` one.

The full code would then be:

```
open System
open System.Web.Mvc
open System.Web.Mvc.Async
open System.Runtime.ExceptionServices

open Unchecked

type AsyncWorkflowController() = 
    inherit AsyncController()

    override __.CreateActionInvoker() = 
        upcast { new AsyncControllerActionInvoker() with

                member __.GetControllerDescriptor(controllerContext) =
                    let controllerType = controllerContext.Controller.GetType()

                    upcast { new ReflectedAsyncControllerDescriptor(controllerType) with 
                            member ctrlDesc.FindAction(controllerContext, actionName) =
                                let forwarder = base.FindAction(controllerContext, actionName) :?> ReflectedActionDescriptor

                                if(forwarder = null || forwarder.MethodInfo.ReturnType <> typeof<Async<ActionResult>>) then
                                    upcast forwarder
                                else 
                                let endAsync' = ref (defaultof<IAsyncResult -> Choice<ActionResult, exn>>)

                                upcast { new AsyncActionDescriptor() with

                                        member actionDesc.ActionName = forwarder.ActionName
                                        member actionDesc.ControllerDescriptor = upcast ctrlDesc
                                        member actionDesc.GetParameters() = forwarder.GetParameters()

                                        member actionDesc.BeginExecute(controllerContext, parameters, callback, state) =
                                            let asyncWorkflow = 
                                                forwarder.Execute(controllerContext, parameters) :?> Async<ActionResult>
                                                |> Async.Catch
                                            let beginAsync, endAsync, _ = Async.AsBeginEnd(fun () -> asyncWorkflow)
                                            endAsync' := endAsync
                                            beginAsync((), callback, state)

                                        member actionDesc.EndExecute(asyncResult) =
                                            match endAsync'.Value(asyncResult) with
                                                | Choice1Of2 value -> box value
                                                | Choice2Of2 why -> 
                                                    // Preserve the stack trace, when rethrow 
                                                    ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(why).Throw() 
                                                    obj() (* Satisfy return value *) } } }
```

Usage:

```
type TestController() =
    inherit AsyncWorkflowController()

    member x.IndexWorks() = async {
        let startThread = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
        let! data = asyncDownload "http://stackoverflow.com"
        let endThread = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagaedThreadId
        return ContentResult(Content = "Start = %i | End = %i" startThread endThread) :> ActionResult }
```

And to confirm that it actually does everything async, and is not blocking any thread from the ASP.NET Pool, use:

```
member x.IndexWorks() = async {
    let startThread = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
    let! data = asyncDownload "http://stackoverflow.com"
    let endThread = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagaedThreadId
    return ContentResult(Content = "Start = %i | End = %i" startThread endThread) :> ActionResult }
```

The start and end thread will differ, hence the start thread was put back into the pool, and a new was returned when the async operation had completed.

Answer (score 8):

async/await uses Tasks, so you'll need to convert back and forth between Task object and F# Async objects. To convert from Task to Async, use `Async.AwaitTask`. To do the opposite use `Async.StartAsTask`. Your example becomes:

```
member x.IndexWorks() =
    async {
        let! data = Async.AwaitTask (DownloadAsync "http://stackoverflow.com")
        return x.Content(data)
    } |> Async.StartAsTask
```

Alternatively, instead of using the `async` computation expression, you can use a computation expression that works for Tasks out of the box. There's one in FSharpx:

```
let task = FSharpx.Task.TaskBuilder()

(...)

member x.IndexWorks() = task {
    let! data = DownloadAsync "http://stackoverflow.com"
    return x.Content(data)
}
```

Comment: on the first option, It says it can't access protected members from within a lambda

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be a bunch of people trying to do something like

```
type SomeController() =
    inherit ApiController()
    member x.Get() =
        let data = Download("http://stackoverflow.com")
        x.Ok(data) :> IHttpActionResult // Using built in Ok, BadRequest, etc.
```

Where `type Get() = unit -> Task<IHttpActionResult>` as expected from a C# WebApi Controller

If you try to do it as the accepted answer suggests (while trying to use the built-in `Ok`, `BadRequest`, etc. methods) you run into

> can't access protected members from within a lambda

To solve this I used the ExtensionMethods directly rather than try to do contort between `async {}` and `Task` that MVC is expecting

```
type SomeController() =
    inherit ApiController()
    member x.Get() = async {
        let! data = DownloadAsync("http://stackoverflow.com") |> Async.AwaitTask
        return System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult(data, x) :> IHttpActionResult // Pass in 'this' pointer (x) into extension method along with data 
    } |> Async.StartAsTask
```

This with the additional upcast `:> IHttpActionResult` you can also return different behavior `BadRequest`, etc from your model and still have it run `async` and the type signatures should work out and compile cleanly